# Flutter: Coverage:ignore not working with async methods

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-test

I can't ignore any async Functions from code coverage. I try to exclude File.exists() from my Code coverage.

Attempts:

- Tried with // coverage:ignore-line -> not working
- Tried with coverage:ignore-start/end -> not working either

My Class File (minimal example):

```
class Coverage{

  bool check(){  // coverage:ignore-line
    return true;  // coverage:ignore-line
  }

  Future<bool> asyncCheck() async {  // coverage:ignore-line
    return true;  // coverage:ignore-line
  }

  bool someIrrelevantFunction(){
    return true;
  }
}
```

My Test File

```
void main() {
  group('Code Coverage Test', () {
    test('just a test', () {
      Coverage cov = Coverage();
      expect(cov.someIrrelevantFunction(), true);
    });
  });
}
```

My coverage:

```
SF:lib\gg.dart
DA:12,0         <-Async Function line, not ignored...
DA:16,1         <-someIrrelevantFunction line
LF:2
LH:1
end_of_record
```

Flutter 2.8, Android Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be working now with Flutter 3.0.0 and Dart version 2.17.0